# Pull report of all possible values(without their record entry)

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am trying to pull a report for timesheet. We are having a user field for the hours. Pulling user report is pretty easy. However we are getting those only users who reported their efforts. Need to pull those users as well who doesn't reported their effort.

Is there any chance we can achieve with the standard reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a Custom Report Type using something like "Users with or without Time Sheets." You can find this option in Setup > Create > Report Types.